# SecKeychainItemImport, SecIdentitySearchCreate, SecIdentitySearchCopyNext

Tags: iphone, cocoa, keychain

SecKeychainItemImport, SecIdentitySearchCreate, SecIdentitySearchCopyNext marked as deprecated. Can anybody can suggest me a resource, where is example how to change those functions to another?

Comment: Accept the answers to your previous questions first.

Comment: @user170317 http://stackoverflow.com/users/979895/user170317, Click on your questions and then the check mark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacements are `SecItemImport`, `SecItemCopyMatching`, and `SecItemCopyMatching`, respectively